# Java inheritance, two-step inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the main abstract class that is a base for bunch of classes. Some of them does not need all the fields and methods from the main abstract class, so I have created second abstract class and splitted main abstract class into two parts. The main abstract class contains, for example, *a, x* fields and their getters/setters, the second abstract class inherits from the main and contains additional *b, c* fields and their getter/setters. There are simple classes that are inheriting from the main class,and more complicated are inheriting from the second class. I want to create objects of each class as instances of the main class. Is it right way to do that? I have to type check and cast when I want to use methods from the second abstract class. It makes my code complicated. How can I solve this problem?

```
MainAbstractClass ---> SecondAbstractClass ---> MyComplicatedClasses
       |
       |
       V
MySimpleClasses
```

Comment: *"I want to create objects of each class as instances of main class."* That doesn't make any sense. Can you reword it?

Comment: *"I must add casts to my objects when I want to use methods added in second abstract class."* If you mean you have `MainAbstractClass x = new MyComplicatedClass();` and you want to use methods from `SecondAbstractClass` or `MyComplicatedClass` on `x`, yes, you would have to cast. And you'd have to be sure `x` is, in fact, an instance of `MyComplicatedClass` (it obviously is in that case, but in general, if the type of `x` is `MainAbstractClass`, that's all you know about it). Which suggests a larger design problem.

Comment: A cast is essentially an ugly way to temporarily get around the compiler's type checking and you're right that the need to use casts is a sign that something can be improved in your design.

Comment: as a supplement to @Jesper's note - if you want to cast in your code - you should start looking for a standard design pattern (or a combination of) that can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One of the OO principles is *Favor composition over inheritance*.

This means that common behavior is not provided through base classes but via Component classes which are passed in via *dependency injection* (preferably as *constructor parameters*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your actual needs.

- You can instead choose to store the extended abstract class specific fields in a class that does not implement your base class and make it a member of more complicated classes.
- You can choose to keep everything in a single base class and nothing forces you to use all the fields of an interface in every class that implemented your interface.
- You can also keep using your approach but since you store the classes as an instance of the base class, it will be hard to read.

I believe that if you think code does not look very good, it is probably not good. However, there is usually no single answer to this kind of design questions and the best solution is relative to your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think this need of type cast is a smell of fragile design. Here when we assume *MyComplicatedClass* **ISA KIND OF** *MainAbstractClass* as shown by TJ Crowder then object must behave as *MainAbstractClass* (meaning it can honor only API of *MainAbstractClass*). If it expects special treatment as *MyComplicatedClass* its false commitment and will need Casting. Such casting (by identifying type) goes against OO principles and kills polymorphism. Later this will end up in Ladder of InstanceOf and type casts as in the scenarios rightly pointed out by T.J. Crowder.

I would suggest readdress the design. e.g. though our all user defined type instances ARE KIND OF *Object*, but we use Object API only for methods defined in Object class. We do not use Object o = new MyClass(). There are occasions in frameworks or like Object.equals() method where type cast is needed as API is defined before even concrete extension is written. But it is not a good idea for such simple complete (without open hooks for extensions) Hierarchies.